# What does it mean when something says (in thousands)

Tags: word-problem

I'm doing a research report, and I need to determine a companies assets. So I found their annual report online, and for the assets, it says (in thousands).

One of the rows is:

Net sales $ 26,234,876

How much would that be in thousands?

*I know the company I'm researching makes more than 26 million in sales, so 26 million would not be the correct reporting.*

Comment: It means "26 million thousands".  Essentially just take all those values and multiply them by $1000$.  So roughly $\$26$ billion in sales.

Comment: Thats what I though, just wanted to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply the number by a 1000. So the answer is
$$26\,234\,876 \times 1000 =  26\,234\,876\, 000.$$
This is approximately 26 billion dollars.

Comment: ok, thats what I read online too. Just wanted to make sure. Thanks

Comment: @David No problem.